# One sample t test in python from scratch - getting incorrect p value

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, statistics

I'm trying to recreate a two-tailed one sample t-test in python from scratch to deepen my understanding, and I seem to have working code for some samples of data, but I found one example does not match the output from scipy.ttest_1samp and I'm trying to figure out why.

The t statistics match but I am getting different p values. Is there something wrong with my t.cdf function that is giving me wrong p values?

My code:

```
sample = [10.81261135, 9.68035252, 9.87293556,  10.06308861,
        9.57381722, 10.00922156, 10.90522431, 9.70843104,
        10.16614481, 10.09447189, 10.51260742, 10.17503686,
        10.38718472, 10.52334431, 9.55808306, 10.24290938,
        10.6048062 , 10.27535938, 9.6329808 ,  9.67338239]
mu = 7.128061097    
sam_mean = np.mean(sample)
sam_std = np.std(sample, ddof=1)
n = len(sample)
df = n-1
t = (sam_mean-mu) / (sam_std / (n**(1/2.)))
p = (scs.t.cdf(t,df))*2
return (t,p)
```

My results:

```
(32.369715406889142, 2.0)
```

Results from scipy.ttest_1samp:

```
Ttest_1sampResult(statistic=32.369715406889142, pvalue=4.3828444145707213e-18)
```

Comment: Shouldn't your p value be the survival function (1 - the cdf) * 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
p = (scs.t.cdf(t,df))*2
```

with

```
p = (scs.t.sf(abs(t),df))*2
```

or with

```
p = min(scs.t.cdf(t,df), scs.t.sf(t, df))*2
```

`t.sf(x, df)` is the [survival function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Survival_function) (i.e. it is `1 - t.cdf(x, df)`).